# Is it possible -or recommended- to index an inline query to improve performance?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

I am not an expert on TSQL but I wonder if such a thing is possible:

Imagine I have a select that joins to a table which is another query's result set:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tProduct
JOIN (SELECT ProductId FROM ...... -- some other joins) tInlineQuey
ON tInlineQuery.ProductId = tProduct.Id 
WHERE tInlineQuery. -- some econdition
```

Is it possible or meaningful to create an indedx on the tInlineQuery so that to apply a filtering on that result set can perform faster?
If so, how is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, you could have suitable indexes on the objects within the subquery, but you can't add an temporary index to the subquery as you have it there. You can query hint the way in which the data is joined, e.g. nested loop, merge or hash join - but the optimizer tends to make the right decision.

An option to get that effect would be to select the results of that subquery into a temp table, and place an index on there, then join to that temp table.

To do this, you would need a stored procedure and to include the following code:

```
SELECT yourFields
INTO #TempTableName
JOIN SomeOtherTables
WHERE SomeField=SomeValue;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX SomeIndexName ON #TempTableName(SomeField,AnotherField);

SELECT *
FROM tProduct p
JOIN #TempTableName t ON t.SomeField = p.SomeField
...

DROP TABLE #TempTableName -- optional, the table will die when it goes out of scope at the end of the procedure.
```

The temp table index doesn't have to be clustered, thats down to your choice.

Comment: If not too complicated, can you write me how I can create an index on the temporary table in my scenerio? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Andrew has an excellent answer, but if this is a subquery you will be using often, another option would be to create an indexed view.  There are several good articles about that, including one I wrote at SqL Server Central titled [On Indexes and Views](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/63963/) .

Comment: +1 : I'd definately agree with that, if it is going to be used a lot, and indexed view may be a better option. (Difficult to tell without usage patterns, insertion rates etc)